# JSON Web Token splitting

Tags: xss, cookies, csrf, jwt

It's been quite a few years since the last time I did web development and I realized many things have changed: instead of stateful server-side sessions with **authentication cookies** and **CSRF tokens** now we have **localStorage/sessionStorage**, **Single-Page Applications**, completely stateless APIs with **JSON Web Tokens** inside `Authorization: Bearer` headers, `__Host- ; HttpOnly; SameSite=Strict; Secure` cookies, `X-Frame-Options: DENY` headers and so on.

However, despite all these improvements, a JWT stored in sessionStorage is still vulnerable to **XSS** whereas storing it in a cookie would still make it vulnerable to **CSRF** on old browsers and **Cross-Origin API** calls.

Would it make sense to **split the JWT** on the server side, have the ***signature* sent as a cookie** while the **rest is held in sessionStorage**, and later reassemble them on the server side for verification? Would there be any downsides or security issues about it? Would it be overkill?

Answer (score 1):

## NO, JSON Web Token splitting would not make sense

According to [this Reddit discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/Frontend/comments/cubcpj/local_storage_vs_cookies_for_auth_tokens/) setting the signature to an `HttpOnly` cookie would prevent it from being read by an injected script but the attacker would still be **capable of sending requests** on behalf of the user with the cookie attached to them.